# WebStorm HTML - Infer Prettier's "printer" type when the object "printers" is of type unknown

Tags: webstorm

In WebStorm, object name `printers` of type unknown in HTML infer to type `Printer` of Prettier. It's quite annoying to see these red marks.

Is there anyway to stop this?

[image]